# can css transition transform hold the end state？

Tags: html, css

animation can do it ，just：

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

but the ‘transition’ ， what can I do let div 'end' in hover state use 'transition'

```
.div-box{
        position: relative;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        transition:all 1s linear ;
    }
    .div-box:hover{
        transform: translate(100px,0);
    }
```

Comment: After mouse is removed? ... You can't, you need a script for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kind of emulate the behavior you need with the following trick:

```
.div-box{
        position: relative;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        transition:all 1s linear 99999s; /* huge delay for non-hovered state! */
    }
    .div-box:hover{
        transform: translate(100px,0);
        transition:all 1s linear; /* immediate transition start on hover */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something close to what you are wanting with pure CSS. Add the following to your CSS, it'll run the animation as long as they are hovering over the object, and it will stop once the animation is complete.

```
.div-box {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.div-box:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```